# Get C++ runtime type during debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Curious if anyone has any ideas on this one; working on a game engine that implements a tree of GameObject's. Various specific game objects inherit from that type ( BouncingBall, StatScreen, or whatever).

```
class GameObject {
    public:
    vector<Component *> Components;
    vector<GameObject *> Children;
    GameObject *Parent;
};
```

So at runtime, the game will have a huge tree of these, all of different types. Unfortunately the objects in the Children vectors are all reported as "GameObject *" in the debugger making it really hard to tell what's what.

Best solution I've come up with is to store the type as a member variable on construction:

```
class GameObject {
    public:
    // ...
    const char *Type;

    // Saves current class name as Type.
    template<class T>
    void StoreTypeName( T *thisPointer ) {
        this->Type = typeid( *thisPointer ).name();
    }
};
```

But then in every object constructor I have to remember to call StoreTypeName:

```
class FancyBlinkingObject : public GameObject {
    public:
    FancyBlinkingObject() {
        StoreTypeName( this );
    }
};
```

Any other possible tricks to just do this automatically? Either on the debugger end (Visual Studio 2012) or in the code?

I thought of maybe some kind of central dynamic cast testing function:

```
if ( dynamic_cast<FancyBlinkingObject *>( basePointer ) ) {
    return "FancyBlinkingObject";
}
if ( dynamic_cast<UglyBlueObject *>( basePointer ) ) {
    return "UglyBlueObject";
}
```

But I can't think of a way to do it without me having to manually maintain the list of if's. Want something totally automatic if possible. :)

Comment: I am not familiar with your compiler/debugger, but assuming that your objects are polymorphic (at least one virtual function) then the type information can be retrieved through the `vptr` (virtual table pointer). You would have to read the documentation of your compiler/debugger to see how to extract that information.

Comment: Cool - wasn't aware that adding a virtual function would change the classification of the object. That actually did the trick - making the GameObject destructor virtual (which I should have done anyway) made the runtime type appear in the debugger. Thanks :)

Comment: How did you intend to use the objects if they did not have a virtual interface? How would you (your code) know what they are?

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing how to do this in gdb

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Each GameObject also has a vector of Component's that define its functionality - so on each frame the GameObject tree is traversed, and its components iterated and tested via dynamic_cast<> . A "Behavior" derived component might have OnUpdate, OnInput virtual methods to call, a "SpriteComponent" might be used by the renderer, etc.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So I guess I've gotten lucky so far and not needed to dynamic_cast<> any objects :)

Comment: @QuadrupleA: `dynamic_cast` requires RunTime Type Information, and RTTI is only available if there are virtual functions... or maybe you mean that the object itself was not polymorphic but the components held inside that object were?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yeah - Component was polymorphic but GameObject was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per David Rodriguez's comment - making GameObject polymorphic (in my case by making the destructor virtual) changed its classification in the debugger and showed a vptr to the runtime type info, which did the trick.

Comment: It's noted in all the documentation for RTTI.  The Wikipedia page as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Comment: Yeah - I'm a C++ noob - have mostly used C#, Java and other languages.